# Creating an object array in java using classes

Tags: java, arrays, class

I'm working on a project where I have a text file with the first line being the size of the array I'll need and then subsequent lines have course information in the following order: dept, num, title. (ex. CSC 101 Basic Computing) My code complies but when it runs the first index in the array becomes the default(i.e. nothing) and therefore the last line in the text file doesn't get stored or printed. I'm wondering how I can fix this error.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Organizer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner fileScanner = null;
        String file;
        File f = null;

        //Create a Do While loop in order to prompt the user for a input file
        //and then continue prompting if the file entered does not exist.

        do {
            try {

                System.out.print("What is the name of the input file? ");
                Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in);
                file = inputReader.nextLine();
                f = new File(file);
                fileScanner = new Scanner(new File(file));

                //Catch the exception and tell the user to try again
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                System.out.println("Error scanning that file, please try again.");

            }
        } while (!f.exists());

        //Testing the Make Array Method
        //System.out.print(makeArray(fileScanner));

        //Testing the print Array Method
        printArray(makeArray(fileScanner));

    }

    public static Course[] makeArray(Scanner s) {

        int arraySize = s.nextInt();
        String title = "";
        String dept = "";
        int num = 0;
        Course[] a = new Course[arraySize];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

            a[i] = new Course(dept, num, title);
            String oneLine = s.nextLine();
            Scanner lineReader = new Scanner(oneLine);
            while (lineReader.hasNext()) {

                dept = lineReader.next();
                a[i].setDept(dept);
                num = lineReader.nextInt();
                a[i].setNum(num);
                while (lineReader.hasNext()) {
                    title = title + lineReader.next() + " ";
                }
                a[i].setTitle(title);
            }
            title = " ";
        }
        return a;
    }


    public static void printArray(Course[] arr) {

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

            System.out.println(arr[i].toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my other class.

```
public static class Course {

    //INSTANCE VARIABLES
    private String dept = "";
    private int num = 0;
    private String title = "";

    //CONSTRUCTORS
    public Course(String dept, int num) {
        this.dept = dept;
        this.num = num;
    }

    public Course(String dept, int num, String title) {
        this.dept = dept;
        this.num = num;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Course() {
        this.dept = "AAA";
        this.num = 100;
        this.title = "A course";
    }

    //SETTER AND GETTER METHODS
    public void setDept(String dept) {
        this.dept = dept;
    }

    public void setNum(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDept() {
        return this.dept;
    }

    public int getNum() {
        return this.num;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    //TOSTRING METHOD
    public String toString() {
        return dept + " " + num + ": " + title;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget where your cursor in your Scanner is at each moment.
`s.nextLine()` will read the whole line and then the cursor will jump to the next line, while `s.nextInt()` will read one int from your line and then stay there. It won't check if this has been the last input for that line.

Just fix your code to:

```
int arraySize = s.nextInt();
s.nextLine();
```

and your code should run just fine!

(also consider changing `a[i].setTitle(title);` to `a[i].setTitle(title.trim());`, since you will always be left with a white space at the end of your title..)

Answer (score 0):

nextInt method does not consume the new line character. Here is a solution that works:

```
public static Course[] makeArray(Scanner s){

    int arraySize = s.nextInt();
    String title = "";
    String dept = "";
    int num = 0;
    Course[] a = new Course[arraySize];
    s.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){

        a[i] = new Course(dept, num, title);
            String oneLine = s.nextLine();
            Scanner lineReader = new Scanner(oneLine);

            while (lineReader.hasNext()){

                dept = lineReader.next();
                a[i].setDept(dept);
                num = lineReader.nextInt();
                a[i].setNum(num);
                while (lineReader.hasNext()){
                    title = title + lineReader.next() + " ";
                }
                a[i].setTitle(title);
            }
            title = " ";
    }   
return a;
```

}